# Link to Images not working Sublime 2

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, sublimetext2

I am working with Wordpress and trying to develop a custom theme. I am using Sublime2 IDE to code. I am testing in Chrome.

I am having difficulty getting an image to appear in the browser. I am no stranger to HTML and cannot seem to figure out why the following code is not working...

```
<img src="images/social/twitter-lg.png" alt="Twitter Icon" title="J2 Design on Twitter">
```

The file is located in a folder names "images" which is in the same directory as header.php which is trying to load the image.

If anyone can help me out I would greatly appreciate it. I am testing locally using WAMP.

SERVER RESPONSE

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:254
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Wed, 24 Apr 2013 23:04:30 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 23:04:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3
Content-Length: 254
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Press F12, click on the **Network** tab, press **Images** on the bottom and see why your request is failing.

Comment: @Blender It is giving 404 error not found... Doesn't make sense as I know for certain the file is in that folder...

Comment: Are you sure that the user of WAMP can access to that file?

Comment: No I am not, Is there a way of checking this?

Comment: @Javacadabra: Click on the row where the image is, scroll to the bottom of the pane on the right, click **View Source** on the **Response Headers** tab and post what the server is responding with. Are you sure the URL is completely correct?

Comment: @Blender I've posted that

Comment: @Javacadabra: Well, that's definitely a 404. Can you access the image directly via that URL?

Comment: No I get this error The requested URL /wordpress-testing/wordpress/images/social/twitter-lg.png was not found on this server.

Comment: @Javacadabra: Is that where the image is located? Or is it in `/wordpress-testing/images/social/twitter-lg.png`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? The image is in the images folder which is located in the wordpress-testing folder.

Comment: @Blender Don't know if it helps but the content type of the file being requested is text/html... should it not be image/png?

Comment: @Javacadabra: The response is a 404, so it's going to return a 404 page. See if my answer fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a relative URL. Make it absolute:

```
<img src="/wordpress-testing/images/social/twitter-lg.png" alt="Twitter Icon" title="J2 Design on Twitter">
```

Relative URLs are relative to the current url, so if you're at `http://localhost/login` and request `images/twitter.png`, you'll get `http://localhost/login/images/twitter.png`.

Comment: Actually your answer did solve it for me. I had to adjust the link a slight bit in order for it to work. This is my link: `/wordpress-testing/wordpress/wp-content/themes/j2-fed/j2-theme-static-html/images/social/twitter-lg.png`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the problem is in the path. AS Blender requested, yes, you can use the absolute path, but this of course would then have to be changed once you upload your theme.

**A more common and perhaps "best practice" approach** is to use PHP to enable to you to still use relative URLs, which are relative to your theme directory.

Try this:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>images/social/twitter-lg.png" alt="Twitter Icon" title="J2 Design on Twitter">
```

The `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` is PHP code that make your relative url relative to your template directory. If your header file is not in the root of your template directory, you may need change the HTML portion of your path, not sure.

Hopefully this helps.